# Reading from a text-file, and putting it into a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

We were tasked Create program that will read data from an input file named students.txt which contains names of the students(sample input is provided). The program will contain the following

classStudent

- private instance variables

lastName - String data type for storing the family name of the student

firstName - String data type for storing the given name of the student

- constructor which accepts two inputs: (String, String). The two inputs represents the lastname and firstname in correct order. The constructor will simply assign the data from the parameters to the instance variables.
- public instance method named toString(), which returns a string data(name of the student) with the following format "lastname, firstname".

class MainApp

- contains the method main() which simply declares a LinkedList  variable named list that can store Student objects**.** The list variable will hold the data read from the input file. After reading the contents of the file, display the names of the students.
- while reading each student data from the file, if the lastname of the student starts with a vowel character, add the student object at the beginning of the list. If it is a consonant then add the student object at the end of the list. The maximum amount of file is 3.

students.txt

```
Ang
Bryan
Santos
Charlie
Chua
Leah
Yee
John
Abas
Ryan
Tulfo
Ram
Ching
Daryl
Tulfo
Dona
Ching
Daniela`
```

MainApp.java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MainApp {
    static class Node{
        Student info;
        Node next;
        public Node(Student info){
            this.info = info;
            next = null;
        }
        public Node(Student info, Node node){
            this.info = info;
            next = node;
        }
        
    }
    static class StudentLinkedList{
        Node head, tail;
        
        public StudentLinkedList(){
            head = tail = null;
        }
        public void addToTail(Node node){
            if(head == null){
                head = tail = null;
                return;
            }
            tail.next = node;
            tail = node;
        }
        
        public void addToHead(Node node){
            if(head == null){
                head = tail = null;
                return;
            }
            node.next =head;
            head = node;
        }
        
        public void printAll(){
            Node temp = head;
            while(temp != null){
                temp.info.toString();
                temp = temp.next;
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main (String args[])throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("students.txt"));
        StudentLinkedList list = new    StudentLinkedList();
        
        String ln, fn;
        Student s;
        Node node;
          while (in.hasNext()) {
              ln =  in.nextLine();
              fn = in.nextLine();
              
              s = new Student(ln,fn);
              node = new Node(s);
          }
          if(in.hasNext())
                in.nextLine();
          in.close(); 
    
    }
   
    
}
```

Student.java

```
public class Student {
    
    private String lastname, firstname;
    
    public Student(String ln, String fn) {
        this.lastname = ln;
        this.firstname = fn;
            
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastname){
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstname){
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastName(){
        return lastname;
    }
    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstname;
    }
    @Override
    public  String  toString(){
        String str = (lastname +", "+ firstname);
        return str;
    }        
    
}
```

this my code so far and I don't know how to proceed after this. Any tips or hints is useful.

Comment: Ideally you'd want to tell us exactly where you are stuck. Not only it helps us answer, but often enough the work you'll need to do to formalize your problem will let you find a solution by yourself.

Comment: I am stuck in outputting the list and checking if the first letter of the lastname is vowel or consosnant.

Comment: You should probably explain what error you encounter or what the expected result is and what you actually get. That being said, your while loop does not look quite correct.

Comment: I can see you're not inserting your student to your list and that you're missing a `list.addNode(node)` in your while loop, but mostly I'm wondering if you didn't went through lots of work that wasn't requested by implementing your own `StudentLinkedList`. The way I read your assignment, your teacher wanted you to use a `LinkedList<Student>`, with which you'd add students simply by using `list.add(student)`. (edit : addFirst / addLast)

Comment: To check if the first letter of the lastname is a vowel or a consonnant you'll want to have a list or array of vowels and to substring the lastname after you read it in your while loop, then test if the list of vowels contains that. A switch/case would work too

Answer (score 0):

What must adding do?

- When tail == null (and head == null)

  ```
  head = newNode
  tail = newNode
  ```
- When tail != null (and head != null)

  ```
  tail.next = newNode
  tail = newNode
  ```

As you see, you are doing too much, complicating things.